Dynamic open graph images for social media sharing on an ionic capcitor react app on firebase
I am building an image based food diary (fueld.ai) that automagically does AI analysis of food items and nutrition from a picture of a plate of food. This is super shareable on social. We want to be able to create dynamic unfurls in social sharing channels by adding the image, title and description to the Opengraph tags for each meal to share. This is difficult with an ionic capacitor app built in React as it cannot use Next.js for server side rendering. I am hosting my backend on Google Firebase, How do I do this?

It took me a LOT of research to achieve this, so want to share with Stack Overflow.
This IS possible, although a lot of sources say it is not. Here are the steps.

Create a cloud function using Express to serve up new headers on the user generated page.
Update your firebase.json to point the share pages to that cloud function.

So at a high level it is quite straightforward, but there are some gotchas I want to share. Here is a more detailed breakdown and explanation of the solution.

Declare the function, this uses v2 functions so be careful of the syntax.

    export const expressAppv2 = onRequest({ region: 'europe-west1'},expressApp);


Add middle ware call to serve the page:

    // Middleware to serve static files
    expressApp.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Gotcha 1: Make sure this static path maps to the 'dist' directory of you app. 'dist' is the folder that the latest versions of Ionic compiles to using Vite. This tells the app where to look for the index.html file.

Add the function that does the work. My function is quite generic so it is useful to include it here

    expressApp.get('/p/:uId/:id', async (req, res) => {
      const { uId, id } = req.params;
    
      // Fetch user content from Firestore
      const userMeal = await getUserMeal(uId, id);
    
      // Read the index.html file from your dist directory
      const indexHtml = fs.readFileSync('./dist/index.html', 'utf8');
    
      // Use cheerio to parse and manipulate the HTML
      const $ = cheerio.load(indexHtml);
    
      // Update or add meta tags
      $('title').text(userMeal.title);
      $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content', userMeal.subTitle);
      $('meta[property="og:title"]').attr('content', userMeal.title);
      $('meta[property="og:description"]').attr('content', userMeal.subTitle);
      $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr('content', userMeal.image);
      $('meta[property="twitter:title"]').attr('content', userMeal.title);
      $('meta[property="twitter:description"]').attr('content', userMeal.subTitle);
      $('meta[property="twitter:image"]').attr('content', userMeal.image);
      
      // If these meta tags don't exist, add them
      if (!$('meta[property="og:type"]').length) {
        $('head').append('<meta property="og:type" content="website" />');
      }
      if (!$('meta[name="twitter:card"]').length) {
        $('head').append('<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />');
      }
    
      // Send the modified HTML
      res.send($.html());
    });

To run this you will have needed to import :
    import * as fs from 'fs'; //For the file path
    import * as cheerio from 'cheerio'; // For the HTML parsing

The key elements of this are:

a) Get the custom user document from firebase
b) Define the correct path to the index.html file specifying ./dist in the
path
c) Parsing the html to replace the generic opengraph / social
tags in the master    index.html page for your site
d) Return the modified html


That is the cloud functions. There are another couple of things to do.
You need to adjust your firebase.json file in your project root directory by adding this hosting json:
    "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/p/**",
        "function": "expressAppv2"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },

This section makes sure the public directory is "dist" and it sets up any page on "/p/**" to call the expressAppv2 we created in the Cloud Functions.
There is one final gotcha.
Gotcha 2: Google Cloud Functions do not have access to the main project folder, they can only access the functions folder in the project.
Therefore, as part of the build process we need to copy the latest version of the index.html file stored in the root directory of your project to the functions folder so the Google Cloud Function can access it.
The code needed to do that is contained in the build script in the package.json in the functions directory.
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && cp -R ../dist .",
...
 },
}

This means that the "cp -R ../dist ." command will run after typescript compiles and it will copy the appropriate build files.
And that works.
This was not that hard in the end, but the research on how to do this took months on and off as I hit many dead ends.
